# Computing log-likelihood on a validation / test set

Tags: python, statsmodels

Regression results from Python's `statsmodels` library include the value `llf`, which is, I recon, the log-likelihood obtained during fitting. I am, however, interested in log-likelihood on new data, those I use in `predict()`. Is there a function (even if undocumented) I can call to obtain it? In particular, I am interested in log-likelihood for `OrderedModel`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computing loglikelihood on new data is not directly possible in statsmodels.
(see for example https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/7947 )
The model loglike method always uses the data, endog, exog and other model specific arrays, that is attached to the model as attributes.

Several models like GLM and standard discrete models like Logit, Poisson have a `get_distribution` method (in statsmodels 0.14) that returns a scipy stats compatible distribution instance for new data similar to predict. This distribution instance has a pdf and logpdf method that can be use to compute the loglikelihood for predictions.

However, that is not yet available for models like OrderedModel.

Two possible workarounds, that might work for most cases (I have not checked for OrderedModel)

- Create a new model with the predict data and then evaluate `model.loglike` with params from the estimated model. This will use nobs and degrees of freedom based on the prediction data and not the original model. So results that depend on those might not be appropriate for some usecases.
- Change the data attributes of the underlying model. That is, assign the new data to model.endog, model.exog and, if necessary, other arrays. Then call the model.loglike method with the estimated parameters.

Both of those are hacks that might work for loglike but might not work for some other model or results statistics.
A proper way would be to write new functions that either compute the loglike directly, or that convert predicted probabilities to create a multinomial distribution instance.

Comment: Thanks. Both hacks work for OrderedModel. Any idea how to calculate the null-model likelihood, `llnull`?

Comment: The null model has an explicit solution, used in `start_params`. However, the null model is independent of explanatory variables and only has constant threshold parameters. It depends on y. OrderedResults.llnull and OrderedModel.start_params should work with the two "hacks".